# Selecting which polygon's attributes to keep after dissolve

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dissolve

I have two polygons, after doing a dissolve I can't choose which polygon's attributes the new dissolved polygon will have. I tried to find a pattern by checking if the bigger's polygon attributes are kept but it does not appear to be the case. The selection seems random. What do you think?

The QGIS version is 3.4.11-Madeira

[image: example]

I suppose the reason it keeps the 63 is that it is higher in the attribute table as a row? Therefore it is normal that it keeps the 63?

**EDIT**

Here in the one layer the dissolve keeps the number that is in the higher position as a row in the attribute table which implies that prevalence is the indicator of which id it will eventually have. But the second layer that has been sorted keeps the same id as the other layer after the dissolve which means that the position in the attribute table may not be of importance in this case.
[image]

Comment: 1) Do u know the attributes you want ? 2) do you know how to aggregate each of these attributes ?

Comment: The Merge button on the Advanced Digitizing toolbar gives you control over what happens to the attributes.

Comment: Cound you please create a new attribute within test1 and temp1 with @row_number ?

Comment: I clicked "new field" in the attribute table but there is not an option to just add a number. How can I proceed?

Comment: @CésarArquero So what is going on?The problem is still there.Shouldn't this be considered very basic? I mean we want to dissolve two polygons and we can't figure out how to select which one's attributes to keep.Is there another way? Performing a merge, asks for layer names but these are in the same layer.

Comment: Could you share that shp with us to try with your own data. I think there must be something with your sorting technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dissolve tool will keep the attributes of the first geometry (by row number or index). In case you want to keep the attributes of the larger element within the group of dissolution you must to sort your shp accordingly (using the complement mmqgis for example). 
Here you have some screenshots of doing a dissolve befores and after a re-sort of the shp.

Shp before dissolve:
[image]

First dissolve:
[image]

Change shp order of elements:
[image]

Dissolve 2:
[image]

As you see, now data of the first element (D) is attached to the table:
[image]

EDIT 1: I insist, the order of the element will define the attributes kept.

Here is the data:

[image]

Reverse sorting:

[image]

Dissolve 1 and dissolve 2:

[image]

Comment: Polygon with id = 32 and another with id = 45 are dissolved the final has id = 32. Later polygon with id = 32 and another with id = 3 are dissolved. The dissolved now has id = 32. How is this possible?Based on your theory it should keep the lowest id.Hence id = 3

Comment: Could you share somehow your shp or some selection of features of it ? I think that may be in your data, your files "id" doesn't correspond with the order of features within the shp.

Comment: I have made an edit in the question to explain what I am talking about. I think I got what you mean though.

Comment: What I meant is that what you see in the table of attributes don't necessarily match the internal order of features. You can try something like: sort by id, then export the shp to gpkg (it will create a new field "fid") and see if the fields "fid" and "id" are in the same order. Execute then dissolve and see if always the attributes of the first one are kept.

Comment: So is my interpretation is correct???: "I suppose the reason it keeps the 63 is because it is higher in the attribute table as a row? Therefore it is normal that it keeps the 63"

Comment: Sorry, that's it ¡

Comment: I decided to test the whole process you suggested (with the sort included) but the results seem weird. Check the new edit to see that even though the sort took place the id that is maintained is still the same number in all the scenarios.

Comment: Check the edited answer. It worked for me. I still think your are not sorting your elements in the right way. I mean, sorting by clicking on the colname will not affect the order of your geometries. Yo must use another tool like the one in mmqgis.

Comment: Exactly. "sorting by clicking on the colname will not affect the order of your geometries". The thing is that I used mmqgis. The "temp1" in my screenshot is the output from the sort using mmqgis.

Comment: Just upload those polygons to wetransfer and let me try